# Polars specify dtypes fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

I am trying to optimize the memory used when reading in a csv file into a polars dataframe as part of a pipeline. I have a large number of columns and I know ahead of time that 2 columns need to be objects, 2 columns need to be int64, and the rest can be uint8. I use the following bit of code to generate the list of dtypes:

```
import polars as pl
a = pl.read_csv("path_to_file.csv", n_rows=100)

dtype_list = []
for col in a.columns:
    if col in ["col1", "col10"]:
        dtype_list.append(pl.Int64)
    elif col in ["col13", "col500"]:
        dtype_list.append(pl.Object)
    else:
        dtype_list.append(pl.UInt8)
```

However when I use the dtype_list created using the above snippet I get the following error:

```
b = pl.read_csv("path_to_file.csv", dtypes=dtypes_list)
```

ComputeError: unsupported data type when reading CSV: u8 when reading CSV

***** EDIT *****

So changing the code to this seems to work, just curious as to why the original did not.

```
import polars as pl
a = pl.read_csv("path_to_file.csv", n_rows=100)

dtype_list = []
columns = []
for col in a.columns:
    columns.append(col)
    if col in ["col1", "col10"]:
        dtype_list.append(pl.Int64)
    elif col in ["col13", "col500"]:
        dtype_list.append(pl.Object)
    else:
        dtype_list.append(pl.UInt8)

b = pl.read_csv("path_to_file.csv", dtypes=dtypes_list, columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be a bug.

In the source code, there's different behavior if it's supplied with both columns and dtypes. Specifically when they're both supplied then it converts it into a dict where the column name is the key and the dtype is the value.

Here's that snippet:

```
if columns and dtypes and isinstance(dtypes, list):
    if len(columns) < len(dtypes):
        raise ValueError(
            "More dtypes overrides are specified than there are selected columns."
        )

    # Map list of dtypes when used together with selected columns as a dtypes dict
    # so the dtypes are applied to the correct column instead of the first x
    # columns.
    dtypes = dict(zip(columns, dtypes))
```

I can't find/figure out where it subsequently deals with `dtypes` when they've remained a list to be sure.